# How to replace values in a column having a comma separated array with values from another table?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables like:

**TABLE 1:**

```
       segment          |            value
------------------------+----------------------------------------
 aaa                    | Eateries
 bbb                    | Car Accessories
 ccc                    | Healthcare
 ddd                    | Electronics
```

**TABLE 2:**

```
       idx               |            segmentids
-------------------------+----------------------------------------
 f9b6d54b-c646-4bbb-b0ec |         [aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd]
 asd7a0s9-c646-asd7-b0ec |         [aaa,bbb]
 gd3355ff-cjr8-assa-fke0 |         [aaa,ddd]
 laksnfo3-kgi5-fke0-b0ec |         [ddd]
```

How can I replace segmentid values in Table 2 so it looks like:

```
       idx               |            segmentids
-------------------------+----------------------------------------
 f9b6d54b-c646-4bbb-b0ec | [Eateries,Car Accessories,Healthcare,Electronics]
 asd7a0s9-c646-asd7-b0ec | [Eateries,Car Accessories]
 gd3355ff-cjr8-assa-fke0 | [Eateries,Electronics]
 laksnfo3-kgi5-fke0-b0ec | [Electronics]
```

I tried using java code to replace Values in backend, but it is painfully slow.

Comment: What is the data type of `segmentids`?  As far as I know, Redshift doesn't support an array type.

Comment: The answer is that you do this even more painfully in Redshift than Java because your data is unnormalized.  Please separate out your CSV data and place each value on its own row.  I don't see a remotely nice way of doing this in Redshift.

Comment: Dynamic sql, or a function call. But as other suggested the data setup is bad

Comment: Datatype for column is varchar only.

Comment: how big is table1?

Comment: Around 1000 records at the moment.

Comment: ok - there is an option to use a python udf - but its not going to be great at that size of table1! in fact very bad. also - if you actually want to process those segments nicely in redshift they will really need to be on separate rows, so - you need to change your source to output 1 row per idx/segmentid combination

Answer (score 1):

Could have been possible with PostgreSQL 9.3 or later using lateral join and split_string, but the lateral join is not supported in redshift.
Unfortunately, Normalization is the only helpful and efficient method I see here. 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.